# Explanation needed of the following code which runs on Google Colab notebook

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
import numpy as np

from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image

uploaded=files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():

  # predicting images
  path='/content/' + fn
  img=image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))

  x=image.img_to_array(img)
  x=np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  images = np.vstack([x])

  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)

  print(classes[0])

  if classes[0]>0:
    print(fn + " is a dog")

  else:
    print(fn + " is a cat")
```

This code allows for a user to upload a image and have it predicted between dog vs cat.

How can I reproduce the same on my local machine ?

Comment: uploading is just a way to provide data, you can change the upload part to a file path and then read and use the image

Comment: Could you guide how to do that ? say the images I want to be predicted are stored in "\Users\root1\Documents\test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from your local.

```
import os, sys
from os import listdir
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

main_dir = "\Users\root1\Documents\test"
files = listdir(main_dir)
# you can change file extension below to read other image types
images_list = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.jpg')] ## output file names only

for idx,image in enumerate(images_list):
  print(idx)

  img=image.load_img(main_dir + image, target_size=(150, 150))

  x=image.img_to_array(img)
  x=np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  images = np.vstack([x])

  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)

  print(classes[0])

  if classes[0]>0:
    print(fn + " is a dog")

  else:
    print(fn + " is a cat")
```